# FFT Implementation on Recorded Position Values

Tags: python, python-2.7, fft

I have created a program that tracks the red dot of a laser over that a person is holding still on a point over 60 second time interval. It records the data of the lasers X and Y position into an excel spreadsheet at around 16-19 Hz currently. (I am looking for means to increase that).

I now have a list of X and Y positions over a time interval and want to convert this into the frequency domain to see if I can possibly find a frequency that the person is moving up and down from breathing, etc. I have been trying to implement an FFT individually for the x and y values but not certain that I am doing this correctly.

The is the function I have created to perform the FFT: (x and y are arrays of the recorded values)

```
def FFT(x, y):
   """
   Preforms a Fast Fourier Transform.
   """

   Fs = 60
   n = len(y)
   T = n/Fs #sampling rate Hz

   t = np.linspace(0,60,n)
   k = np.arange(n)

   frq = k/T
   freq = frq[range(n/2)]

   yf = fft(y)/n
   yf = yf[range(n/2)]

   plt.figure(1)
   plt.subplot(211)
   plt.xlabel('time')
   plt.ylabel('Y')
   plt.plot(t,y, 'bo')

   plt.figure(1)
   plt.subplot(212)
   plt.axis([0.0,60.0,0.0,20.0])
   plt.plot(freq, abs(yf)*2)
   plt.show()
```

So far I have generated the following graphs:

[image: graphs showing 'Y positions vs time' and the 'FFT']

Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The only problem I see is that you have `Fs = 60` but you say that your sample rate is "16-19 Hz" - so your frequency axis will be wrong, if that's the case. (Are you confusing your 60 second sample period with your sample rate, I wonder ?). A couple of minor things that you might want to add: apply a window function and use a log axis for the power spectrum magnitude - this should make your spectrum look "better".

Comment: I may have confused the values. The 60 represents the time interval while the 16-19 Hz is the rate at which the values were recorded. This was calculated using the total number of collected values divided by the sampling interval (60) (which gave specifically 16 Hz for this experiment). However I may be mis-understanding this since i followed guidelines I found on stackoverflow.

Comment: OK - sample rate (usually denoted by `Fs`) is the no of samples per second. So if you sample for say 3 seconds and get 60 samples then Fs = 60/3 = 20 Hz. Sample rate needs to be uniform, and it will determine the frequency axis of your spectrum plot (e.g. if Fs = 20 Hz then your frequency axis will be 0 .. 20 / 2 = 10 Hz (aka the Nyquist frequency)).